# Format function calls syntax with sed

Tags: bash, sed, parentheses

I would like to format the syntax of function calls in some fortran program and I can't find an approach fulfilling my needs.

The possible syntax encountered in the source code can be:

```
func_example( x,y,z )
other_func_example(x,y,z, t)
another_one( x,y )
...
```

The syntax I need is exactly:

```
func_example(x, y, z)
other_func_example(x, y, z, t)
another_one(x, y)
...
```

I found a sed solution that completely removes spaces between curly braces:

```
echo -e "function{x,y,z}\n function{ x,y,z}\n function{x,y,z }\n function{ x,y,z }" 
| sed -e '/{/,/}/{s#\s*##g}'
```

This provides:

```
function{x,y,z}
function{x,y,z}
function{x,y,z}
function{x,y,z}
```

This is close to what I need but there are still issues:

- Won't work with standard parentheses. I should escape them in a way I can't get to.
- Leaves no space after commas

I would appreciate any help on this. Sed seems to me as the best option. I would also accept any full bash or awk solution, but I'd like to avoid using perl as I know almost nothing about it.

Comment: `Won't work with standard parentheses. I should escape them in a way I can't get to.` what do you mean? Just don't escape them. | What is the valid character set for each token? What are allowed characters for `function` name and parameters? -> Then match each token (function name, parameter name) with sed using `\([ .. ]\)` ->  and with sed output matching `\1{\2, \3, \4}` line. You can learn regex fast using https://regexcrossword.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an awk solution that is probably not the most clever one, but it works for any number of comas.  The idea is to generate a script containing some sed commands to be launched.
I share it in case it could be of any help for some reader.

Input test file:

```
some_func(x, y,z)
some_func_a(x, y, z, t )
some_func_b(x,y,z)
some_func_z(x, y , z)
some_func(x, y , z )
! some comment
some_func( x, y)
some_func_1(x)
some text
some_func(x, z, a, b,e)
some_func_da(x, y,d, z)
some_func_bla( x, y, z)
some_text without parenthesis
```

The script I came to looks like:

```
while read line
do
    # Gets what's in parenthesis and the function name
    in_par=$(echo $line|awk -F "[()]" '/\(/{print "(" $2 ")" }')
    func_name=$(echo $line|awk -F "[()]" '/\(/{print $1}')
    # Formats to my desired format
    in_par_mod=$(echo $line|awk -F "[()]" '/\(/{print $2}'|awk '{ gsub (" ", "", $0); print}'|awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=", "} {$1=$1; print "(" $0 ")"}')
    # Re-buils full patterns
    in_name=$func_name$in_par
    mod_name=$func_name$in_par_mod
    printf " Before : %-30s  After : %-30s \n" "$in_name" "$mod_name"
    # Generating script to be launched
    if [ ! -z "$in_name" ]
    then
        printf "sed -i 's/%s/%s/g' %s \n " "$in_name" "$mod_name" "$in_file" >> sed_script.sed
    else
        printf "Line contains nothing to change \n"
    fi
done < $in_file
```

Running it yields:

```
 Before : some_func(x, y,z)               After : some_func(x, y, z)
 Before : some_func_a(x, y, z, t )        After : some_func_a(x, y, z, t)
 Before : some_func_b(x,y,z)              After : some_func_b(x, y, z)
 Before : some_func_z(x, y , z)           After : some_func_z(x, y, z)
 Before : some_func(x, y , z )            After : some_func(x, y, z)
Line contains nothing to change
 Before : some_func( x, y)                After : some_func(x, y)
 Before : some_func_1(x)                  After : some_func_1(x)
Line contains nothing to change
 Before : some_func(x, z, a, b,e)         After : some_func(x, z, a, b, e)
 Before : some_func_da(x, y,d, z)         After : some_func_da(x, y, d, z)
 Before : some_func_bla( x, y, z)         After : some_func_bla(x, y, z)
Line contains nothing to change
Line contains nothing to change
```

And generates the following script:

```
sed -i 's/some_func(x, y,z)/some_func(x, y, z)/g' in.txt
sed -i 's/some_func_a(x, y, z, t )/some_func_a(x, y, z, t)/g' in.txt
sed -i 's/some_func_b(x,y,z)/some_func_b(x, y, z)/g' in.txt
sed -i 's/some_func_z(x, y , z)/some_func_z(x, y, z)/g' in.txt
sed -i 's/some_func(x, y , z )/some_func(x, y, z)/g' in.txt
sed -i 's/some_func( x, y)/some_func(x, y)/g' in.txt
sed -i 's/some_func_1(x)/some_func_1(x)/g' in.txt
sed -i 's/some_func(x, z, a, b,e)/some_func(x, z, a, b, e)/g' in.txt
sed -i 's/some_func_da(x, y,d, z)/some_func_da(x, y, d, z)/g' in.txt
sed -i 's/some_func_bla( x, y, z)/some_func_bla(x, y, z)/g' in.txt
```

I would still appreciate any help or comment to improve this method.

Answer (score 2):

The following:

```
echo 'function( x,y,z )
function(x,y,z)
function(x, y,z)' |
sed 's/\(function\)([[:space:]]*\([a-z]*\)[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*\([a-z]*\)[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*\([a-z]*\)[[:space:]]*)/\1(\2, \3, \4)/'
```

outputs:

```
function(x, y, z)
function(x, y, z)
function(x, y, z)
```

It:

1. Matches `function([a-z]*,[a-z]*,[a-z]*)` with any number of `[[:space:]]*` whitecharacters (spaces, tabs) between all the tokens.
2. Remembers the name of the function and the parameters names, using sed's `\(...\)`
3. Then outputs the tokens with spaces and commas `\1(\2, \3, )`
4. Note that it will also kind-of work for strange inputs, like `function(,,)`
5. If you are formatting some C code, use `astyle` or `indent` or other utility created for doing that.

Comment: Nice answer, even though it does not adresses two points (that I haven't precised in my question... my bad)

- It works only with the keyword function 
- It works for exactly three arguments

I'm adding these in the initial question.

Comment: You can change `[a-z]*` for `[a-z]\+` to make `sed`'s regex match one or more characters. `*` matches _zero_ or more, `+` matches one or more. To match any function, replace `function` in the regex for `[a-z]\+` or similar regex. Nothing will save you from understanding it.

Comment: Och, so there is variable number of arguments? That makes `sed` unusable and very hard. You have two solutions -  write `sed` expression to match each number of number of arguments 's/fucntion(onearg)//;t;s/function(twoargs,twoargs)/.../;t; .... `. Or move to `awk` and similar.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to remove spaces around the commas first, you can use

```
...  | sed -r 's/([(,]) */\1/g; s/ ([),])/\1/g; s/,/, /g'
```

Alternative: You can start to remove all spaces with `tr` or simple

```
...  | sed 's/ //g; s/,/, /g'
```